# Regex. How to match special marker parsing correspond value near it?

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse some rfc-5545 rules. My rule examples:

```
"EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20170622,20170713"
"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH"
"EXDATE;TZID=America/New_York:19970714T083000"
"EXDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME;TZID=America/New_York:19970714T083000"
"EXDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20170622T000000,20170713T000000"
"EXDATE:19960402T010000Z,19960403T010000Z,19960404T010000Z"
```

Let's consider more detailly group results that I need:

```
EXDATE  ;VALUE=DATE                              : 20170622,20170713
RRULE                                            : FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH
EXDATE                    ;TZID=America/New_York : 19970714T083000
EXDATE  ;VALUE=DATE-TIME  ;TZID=America/New_York : 19970714T083000
EXDATE  ;VALUE=DATE-TIME                         : 20170622T000000,20170713T000000
EXDATE                                           : 19960402T010000Z,19960403T010000Z,19960404T010000Z
```

// I've implemented it now

```
1group | 2group                                  | 3group
```

### Requeres

```
1group | 2group         | 3group                 | 4group
```

where:

- 2group should detect `VALUE` and parse value of it
- 3group should detect `TZID` and parse value of it

Right now I've prepared pattern for 3 groups only (where no separating for groups to get `VALUE` and `TZID`). Web example is [here](https://regex101.com/r/YlOjuE/1).

My java sample for someone who more familiar with java code than with web tool:

```
public static void parseRule(String rulePattern) {
    String matchPattern = "^(RRULE|EXDATE)+(.*).*:(.*).*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rulePattern);
    System.out.println(matcher.find());
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String group = matcher.group(i);
        System.out.println(i + " : " + group);
    }
    System.out.println("===========");
}

public static void main(String[]s) {
    parseRule("EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20170622,20170713");
    parseRule("RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH");
    parseRule("EXDATE;TZID=America/New_York:19970714T083000");
    parseRule("EXDATE;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20170622T000000,20170713T000000");
    parseRule("EXDATE:19960402T010000Z,19960403T010000Z,19960404T010000Z");
}
```

As I wrote, I need 2group to detect `VALUE` and parse value of it (in 2nd group) and detect `TZID` and parse value of it (in 3rd group) also. Example:

```
1group | 2group    | 3group           | 4group

EXDATE   DATE                         : 20170622,20170713
RRULE                                 : FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH
EXDATE               America/New_York : 19970714T083000
EXDATE   DATE-TIME   America/New_York : 19970714T083000
EXDATE   DATE-TIME                    : 20170622T000000,20170713T000000
EXDATE                                : 19960402T010000Z,19960403T010000Z,19960404T010000Z
```

How I do?

Comment: Using named groups : [`^(?P<group1>RRULE|EXDATE)(?:;VALUE=(?P<group2>[^:;]+))?(?:;TZID=(?P<group3>[^:;]+))?:(?P<group4>.*).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qJxoMm/1)
Or without them : [`^(RRULE|EXDATE)(?:;VALUE=([^:;]+))?(?:;TZID=([^:;]+))?:(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/qJxoMm/2)

Comment: [^(RRULE|EXDATE)+(?:;VALUE=)*(DATE-TIME|DATE)*(?:;TZID=)*(.*):(.*).*$](https://regex101.com/r/yjWr6K/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your grouping parentheses exist in your expression, the group will exist. You can use this to have:

- a first group containing EXDATE or RRULE : `^(EXDATE|RRULE)`
- a second group containing the value if it exists `(?:;VALUE=([^;:]+))`
- a third group containing the tzid if it exists `(?:;TZID=([^;:]+))`
- a fourth group containing what's left after the `:` : `:(.+)$`

Which leaves you with [`^(RRULE|EXDATE)(?:;VALUE=([^:;]+))?(?:;TZID=([^:;]+))?:(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/qJxoMm/2)

Edit: `[^;:]+` means any sequence of characters that are different from `;`and `:`.

Comment: I've configured [^(RRULE|EXDATE)+(?:;VALUE=)*(DATE-TIME|DATE)*(?:;TZID=)*(.*):(.*).*$](https://regex101.com/r/yjWr6K/1) but your version I like more than mine.

Comment: What's mean the construction`([^;:]+)`?